# XSLT 2 analyze-string finding block names

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, unicode

I am trying to detect strings in other languages in my XML.

I thought I could use something like :

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$mystring" regex="(\p{InGreek})" >
```

but I am unable to make this work.

Do you think this is possible in XSLT ? How would you do this ?

Thanks a lot.
Maria
(XSLT 2, Saxon-HE 9.8.0.8)

Comment: Please show an example of input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: And show your best effort; and don't tell us it doesn't work, tell us how it fails. This all makes it much easier for us to see what you've done wrong, and to set you on the right road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right category name would be `IsGreek` so the regular expression would be `\p{IsGreek}`, however as the `regex` attribute of `xsl:analyze-string` allows attribute value templates you either need to put the expression into a string variable `<xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string">\p{IsGreek}</xsl:param>`you reference as `regex="{$pattern}"` or you need to duplicate the curly braces, as in `regex="\p{{IsGreek}}"`.

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I needed. Have a wonderful day.